# Stop the lines overlapping the text attribute in d3 - forced graph?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have the following svg which has text in the middle of a larger circle and which is connected to two other smaller circles with a line.

The line co-ordinates are obtained by the following formula:

```
        x1={Math.max(radius, Math.min(height - radius, link.source.x))}
        y1={Math.max(radius, Math.min(width - radius, link.source.y))}
        x2={Math.max(radius, Math.min(height - radius, link.target.x))}
        y2={Math.max(radius, Math.min(width - radius, link.target.y))}
```

and the circle and text node is obtained as follows:

```
<circle r="100"
            transform={translate(
                        ${Math.max(100, Math.min(height - radius, source.x))},
                        ${Math.max(100, Math.min(width - radius, source.y))}}/>
            <text dx="-20"
                        transform={translate(
                        ${Math.max(100, Math.min(height - radius, source.x))},
                        ${Math.max(100, Math.min(width - radius, source.y))})}>sometext</text>
```

[image]

How can i stop the lines from starting the center of the circle and start them from the edges of the circle so as to prevent the overlap on the text??

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Draw the lines first and the circles second.

Answer (score 2):

There is no z-index or anything like that in an SVG. In an SVG, the order of the drawing determines who stays on top and who goes to the bottom: just like a real painter laying ink in a real canvas, what is painted **first** remains at the bottom, and what is painted **later** stays on the top, and it is visible.

Since you didn't share your code, this is the general solution: in the script, change the order of the selections that append the elements, so they appear in this order:

1. The lines' selection
2. The circles' selection
3. The texts' selection.